# Craft CMS V3 Create New User

Tags: craft3, yii

Having difficulties creating a new user in a custom controller, here's my implementation:

`use craft\records\User;`

```
$user = new User;
$user->firstName = $userData['firstName'];
$user->lastName = $userData['lastName'];
$user->username = $userData['loginName'];
$user->email = $userData['loginName'];
$user->password = $userData['password'];

$response = $user->insert();
```

Response:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_users` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `dateCreated`, `uid`, `dateUpdated`) VALUES ('Tristan', 'Gemus', 'registertest@gmail.com', 'registertest@gmail.com', 'password', '2019-03-28 15:53:10', '85468ad6-63cc-499d-baf4-32aaaf55bfb2', '2019-03-28 15:53:10')
```

The response returns false. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Craft's own [UsersController->actionSaveUser()](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L919-L1212).

You're probably looking for something closer to this:

```
$user = new craft\elements\User();

$user->firstName = $firstName;
$user->lastName = $lastName;
$user->username = $userName;
$user->email = $email;
$user->password = $password;

if ($user->validate(null, false)) {
    Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user, false);
}
```

Comment: I've found that if you actually want to set the password, you need to use `$user->newPassword = $password;` Other than that, this works exactly as expected, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. What is `$user->validate(null, false)`?